# Unreasonable Error in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using

```
System.loadLibrary("native1");
```

where libnative1.so is dependent on other .so 's. I have added each such .so into the Distributed Cache. Interestingly, if I do not add any one of the .so it throws the corresponding exception (that this particular .so was not found). That means, all dependencies *are* present in the Mapper. 
Then why am I getting this weird & unreasonable error when I am loading native1.so ?

```
IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 134 hadoop
```

I couldn't find any solution to this .. hence any help would be very good .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are in the task logs? Googling your error leads to lots of results.

Comment: The error that I wrote above was from the mapper itself.. I couldn't find a meaningful solution to this error..

Comment: What is in the task logs? A code 134 means the JVM crashed. Does your code that uses the native libraries work outside of hadoop? Have you tried upping the amount of task memory?

Comment: No, I m using JNI to call those native libraries; and it seems I am loading too many libraries exceeding the upper limit of the task. Do you have an idea about which parameter has to be upped?